# How to change Google account linking default text

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm building an action using Dialogflow fulfillment library and had to integrate Google sign in account linking to the action. With new SignIn("some text"), "some text" is displayed and then the rest is the default text!
I wonder if it is possible to change this default text provided by Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot change the default text as it's intended to create a consistent user experience.